# regasm registry error

Tags: regasm

I enter this:

> regasm COMTest.dll /tlb:COMTest.tlb /codebase COMTest

And I get the following error:

> An error occurred while registering the exported type library: Error
>   accessing the OLE registry. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801C
>   (TYPE_E_REGISTRYACCESS))

What does it mean, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution - I thought I was administrator, but it seems that I have to run cmd as adminstrator.  (Right click cmd and select that option)

You learn something new everyday :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this if you mistype the filepath/name of the tlb file parameter.  My coworker was using the following: **regasm dummy.dll /tlb:*dummy.dll* /codebase** and got the same error.